# ReferenceError when importing gapi from Playwright test

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, google-api-js-client

The following is a simple test to get the OIDC token using [gapi client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client)

```
// example.spec.ts
test("get oidc token", async ({ page }) => {
  gapi.load("client", () => {
    gapi.client
      .init({
        apiKey: "*****",
        clientId:
          "********",
        discoveryDocs: [
          "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1",
        ],
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return gapi.client.request({
          path: "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/...:generateIdToken",
          ...
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .then((token) => console.log(`OIDC token ${token}`));
  });
});
```

It won't work as it raises a `ReferenceError: gapi is not defined` even though the `@types/gapi` are installed.

I've already tried to add `"gapi"`/`"@types/gapi"` in `types` inside the `tsconfig.json` file or `import 'gapi'` without any success.

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to use the gapi client from Playwright or not.

Comment: Did you import/require gapi from the library? or is it even possible to do that?

Comment: I've already tried to add "gapi"/"@types/gapi" in types inside the tsconfig.json file or import 'gapi' without any success